# Setting model's FK through MVVM data-binding (from a combobox)

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, data-binding, foreign-keys

This is my first WPF MVVM EF project and while the experience has been very rough and I doubtI'll ever be coming back to these, I'm intent on finishing it. I have a view where you can edit `Hardware` model's properties. It works just fine for the 'simple' properties such as strings, ints, DateTime and so on. But for some reason I can't make it work with the few FK properties this model has.
Here's the view-viewModel-model code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFapp.Views.HardwareManipulationWindowView">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type localVM:HardwareManipulationViewModel}">
            <local:HardwareManipulationWindowView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Hardware.CurrentlyBeingUsedByProgram.GUID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ProgramsList}" SelectedValuePath="GUID">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</UserControl>

internal class HardwareManipulationViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    public HardwareManipulationViewModel(Hardware hardware, ObservableCollection<Program> programsList)
    {
        Hardware = hardware;
        ProgramsList = programsList;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Program> ProgramsList { get; set; }

    public Hardware Hardware { get; }

    internal void WriteChangesInto(Hardware selectedItem)
    {
        selectedItem.Type = Hardware.Type;
        selectedItem.Label = Hardware.Label;
        selectedItem.Description = Hardware.Description;
        selectedItem.Remarks = Hardware.Remarks;
        selectedItem.CurrentLocation = Hardware.CurrentLocation;
        selectedItem.CurrentStatus = Hardware.CurrentStatus;
        //all of the above work just fine, but these 2 FKs below don't work at all
        selectedItem.CurrentlyBeingCarriedByPerson = Hardware.CurrentlyBeingCarriedByPerson; 
        selectedItem.CurrentlyBeingUsedByProgram = Hardware.CurrentlyBeingUsedByProgram;
    }
}

public class Hardware : NotificationObject
{
    protected Hardware()
    {
        GUID = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    Guid _guid;
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid GUID { get { return _guid; } private set { _guid = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

    string _label;
    public string Label { get { return _label; } set { _label = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
    string _description;
    public string Description { get { return _description; } set { _description = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
    string _remarks;
    public string Remarks { get { return _remarks; } set { _remarks = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

    Program _currentlyBeingUsedByProgram;
    public Program CurrentlyBeingUsedByProgram { get { return _currentlyBeingUsedByProgram; } set { _currentlyBeingUsedByProgram = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
}
```

I've obviously omitted a lot of noise code. For anyone wondering `NotificationObject` is the basic `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation. Now, all of the above is handled inside this single method:

```
private void InvokeEditHardwareDialog()
{
    HardwareManipulationViewModel viewModel = new HardwareManipulationViewModel(SelectedItem.Clone(), new ObservableCollection<Program>(_dbContext.EagerLoad<Program>()));
    var window = WindowService.CreateWindowHostingViewModel(viewModel, true);
    window.ShowDialog();
    if (viewModel.DialogResult.GetValueOrDefault())
    {
        viewModel.WriteChangesInto(SelectedItem);
        _dbContext.Update(SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is: when the debugger goes into that `WriteChangesInto` method, all the props above the comment line I've inserted there have their new values as changed using the view, but for the last 2 (foreign key) properties nothing happens, despite the combobox values loading properly. `Hardware.CurrentlyBeingUsedByProgram` contains whatever the value it started with. What am I doing wrong here? By all my knowledge this should work just fine.

Comment: Bit hard to answer this without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but can you pls post your code for the Program class? I suspect its GUID isn't a property.

Comment: Posting MCVE would basically require uploading whole project (EF and my interface for it, commands, helper classes, etc), and since I don't see any options for file uploading in post editing options, I'm guessing it's not a welcomed practice on this site. I will edit the post and add GUID code as well though.

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't that hard, so an MCVE shouldn't be too difficult to put together. Of course, what often happens is that in the process of doing that you figure out what the problem is anyway. I'll come back a little later, good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is most likely between EF and WPF communication. I ended up using a workaround, which involves using an additional property to store the FK value:

```
private Program _hardwareProgram;
public Program HardwareProgram { get { return _hardwareProgram; } set { _hardwareProgram = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
```

And XAML:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding HardwareProgram}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding ProgramsList}"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
```

Then in your ctor you just read that value `_hardwareProgram = hardware.CurrentlyBeingUsedByProgram;` and you're good to go.